# Reading JSON data returned from ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

This is my data:

```
[{"ServiceId":4,"ServiceName":"first sevice","ServiceCriteria":"Lumpsum","ItemBasis":"Inward/Outward","Currency":null,"Amount":null}]
```

How can I read this data when it's passed back from a controller in the success?

```
  $('#btnservice').click(function () {
        var url = "/Quotation/SelectService/";
        var selservice = $("#selservice").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: { selservice: selservice },
            cache: false,               
            dataType: 'json',
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {               

                $("#Services").empty();
            },
            error: function (reponse) {
                alert("error : " + reponse);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

you can read like this

```
 var a = [{ "ServiceId": 4, "ServiceName": "first sevice", "ServiceCriteria": "Lumpsum", "ItemBasis": "Inward/Outward", "Currency": null, "Amount": null}];
        alert(a[0].ServiceId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your controller side must be like this

```
public string SelectService(string ServiceId, string ServiceName, string ServiceCriteria, string ItemBasis, string Currency, string Amount)
{
    string message = string.Empty;
    //do whatever you want here and return message like 
    message=success;
    return message;
}
```

Than in view page check if return value is success or not.

```
    success: function (data) {               
         if(data=="success" )
         {
            //to do
            $("#Services").empty();
         }
         else
         { 
            //bla bla
         }
   },
   error: function (reponse) {
   alert("error : " + reponse);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your JSON string is returned by the controller. You can access the return data in the `success` callback. Your `data` variable already contains this response.

```
$('#btnservice').click(function () {
    var url = "/Quotation/SelectService/";
    var selservice = $("#selservice").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: { selservice: selservice },
        cache: false,               
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {               
            var service = data[0];

            alert(service.ServiceName); // Should be "first service"

            $("#Services").empty();
        },
        error: function (reponse) {
            alert("error : " + reponse);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I use following code and it works good:

```
success: function (data) {
     $.each(data, function (index, item) {
     alert(data[index].ServiceId)
     alert(data[index].ServiceName)    
     .............................
     .............................
     //other properties you want to get                      
     });
    }
```